# How can I access the position of a certain tile in a tilemap (unity 2D)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, collider

I am currently trying to find a way to get the position of the specific tile that I collide with. I have a large tilemap with a tilemap collider, and I have a player that has a script (seen below) that should on collision with a tile from that tilemap instantiate a pickup item a random range away from that tile. But because it is the tilemap collider that I am colliding with, the pickups spawn a random distance from 0,0 where the tilemap is positioned. Is there a way I can access the position of the individual tile so that the pickups spawn a random distance from the tile I collide with (or do you have another idea of how to create the same effect)?
Thanks so much!

**Script:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Drops : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject wooddropling;
    public GameObject stonedropling;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "trees")
        {
            Instantiate(wooddropling, new Vector3(col.transform.position.x - Random.Range(-3f, 3f), col.transform.position.y - Random.Range(-3f, 3f), 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f)));
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "stones")
        {
            Instantiate(stonedropling, new Vector3(col.transform.position.x - Random.Range(-3f, 3f), col.transform.position.y - Random.Range(-3f, 3f), 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, Random.Range(0.0f, 360.0f)));`
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/best-way-to-detect-collision-between-tile-and-other-object-and-get-tile-position.617863/) and [another](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154045/how-can-i-get-the-specific-tile-in-a-collision-with-a-tilemap), you can use collision overlap checks to find tile/positions within the TileMap:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        ContactPoint2D contact = collision.GetContact(0);
        // Assuming 'tilemap' is your TileMap object.
        Vector3Int cellPosition = tilemap.WorldToCell(contact.point);

        // If you need the tile itself.
        TileBase tile = tilemap.GetTile(cellPosition);
        // Or, if you need the tile's position:
        Vector3 tilePosition = tilemap.CellToWorld(cellPosition)
    }
```

Though given that those referenced posts are old *(2015~2018)*, someone might post a more efficient answer.