# Unity2D Get position of tile which the player is colliding with RayCastHit2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Trying to achieve** a "grab ledge" functionality, but im struggling to make it "look" good by getting the position of the "Ledge" tile that the player "can grab" and adjusting the player position accordingly with that tile. I already managed to transition to the animation, detect a valid ledge to grab on and grab, but im missing the positioning when grabbing the ledge to be accordingly... I am trying to get the position of the tile the player is colliding or grabbing to with a `RayCastHit2D`.

**The problem** is the tile position is always 0, and it took me a little to understand that it is because the `Grid` object Transform component position is `(0, 0, 0)` (atleast this is the reason I think that makes the tiles have this position too, because tiles are inside Grid object), so my question is how to get the position of the tile that the RayCast2D actually collided with?

What I tried was also using the RigidBody2D of the tile but it does not work, still always being `0,0,0` the position.

Here is my current code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    playerObj = GameObject.Find("Player");
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(playerObj.transform.position, Vector2.right, 1f, LayerMask.GetMask("Ledgeonly"));
    RaycastHit2D hitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(playerObj.transform.position, Vector2.left, 1f, LayerMask.GetMask("Ledgeonly"));

    // Check if the ray hit a ledge collider
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        // Handle the ledge collision (e.g., set CanGrabLedge to true)
        CanGrabLedge = true;
        ledgeY = hit.collider.transform.position.y;
    }
    else if (hitLeft.collider != null)
    {
        // Handle the ledge collision (e.g., set CanGrabLedge to true)
        CanGrabLedge = true;
        ledgeY = hitLeft.collider.transform.position.y;
    }
    else
    {
        CanGrabLedge = false;
    }
    Debug.Log("LedgeY is: " + ledgeY);
}
```

And the following image is how my Grid looks at the Unity Scene:

[image]

As you can see there are currently 3 tiles I have there, but no matter which one I grab to (RaycastHit2D collides with), ledgeY is always 0!

**Update**:

The result im expecting is that it does not matter which of the tiles the Player grabs, the position is always according to the tile, for example in the following images you can see the Player is grabbing and it makes sense from where he grabs (how it looks):

[image: expected result]

another example:

[image: expected result2]

but sadly sometimes I get this result:

[image: unexpected]

Im not sure if the problem is at my PlayerController when it grabs:

```
public void OnLedgeGrab(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    // If already grabbing then ungrab
    if (context.started && touchingDirections.IsGrabbingLedge)
    {
        // Tell the animation to transition
        touchingDirections.IsGrabbingLedge = false;
        animator.SetBool(AnimationStrings.isGrabbingLedge, touchingDirections.IsGrabbingLedge);
        rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Dynamic;
        animator.SetBool(AnimationStrings.canMove, true);
    }
    // If the player is not in the ground, can grab a ledge and is not already grabbing a ledge then grab
    else if (context.started && !touchingDirections.IsGrounded && touchingDirections.CanGrabLedge && !touchingDirections.IsGrabbingLedge)
    {
        // Tell the animation to transition
        touchingDirections.IsGrabbingLedge = true;
        animator.SetBool(AnimationStrings.isGrabbingLedge, touchingDirections.IsGrabbingLedge);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        rb.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic;
        // Here im trying to use the ledgeY position we calculated before so that it would make sense from where the player grabs to the tile
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, touchingDirections.ledgeY);
        animator.SetBool(AnimationStrings.canMove, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: The [`RaycastHit2D.point`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-point.html) is not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Bounds.ClosestPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.ClosestPoint.html) function.

e.g: `hit.collider.bounds.ClosestPoint(playerObj.transform.position)`.

And, if you want to do a climbing function. Here is another idea: if the player is in the air,he will drop down, because of the gravity. And if the player is grabbed something(*ledge*), he will stop dropping immediately, or slide down a little bit.  That's it, you don't need to care about the position of the collider hit point.

---

Update:  how to get the left-top position of a tile.

Reference:

- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetCellCenterWorld.html
- https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GridLayout.WorldToCell.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76838505/11226492

Example code(*NOT tested*)

```cs
void SomeFunction(){
    var tilemap = hit.collider.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
    var centerOfTile =  tilemap.GetCellCenterWorld(tilemap.WorldToCell(hit.point));
    var tileWidthHalf = 64 / 2;     // 64 is an example value.
    var tileHeightHalf = 64 / 2;    // 64 is an example value.
    // assume y+ is top,  x+ is right.
    var leftTop = new Vector3(centerOfTile.x - tileWidthHalf, centerOfTile.y +  tileHeightHalf, centerOfTile.z);
}
```

The main idea is:

- Calc the center(*or left-bottom*) position of the tile.
- Add some offset(*calc by the tile size*).

Thanks @derHugo to point out the `point` property.

Comment: With this way atleast ledgeY is now updating, but im not getting the dessired result, I had to use it like this (notice I added the .y):

ledgeY = hit.collider.bounds.ClosestPoint(playerObj.transform.position).y;

but still the grabbing to the tiles is not 100% consistent, I will update question with image of what im expecting and also some more code

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast I'm not sure what your purpose is. If the player was grabbed a tile, what's your expectation of the player position?  A: the player's current position. B: some position base by the tile(*e.g left top corner of the tile*).  C: the player's current position, but it shouldn't above of the tile.

Comment: Yes the left top corner of the tile is my expectation, see my update on the question I posted images to help see expécted results

Comment: This worked as expected, just needed to adjust the 64 to the size of my tile size which is around 0.8 or so, ty